# JPA : Inheritance - Discriminator value not taken into account in generated SQL

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance, jpa

I try to use this mapping :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ecc.\"RATE\"")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class Rate extends GenericBusinessObject {
...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("E")
public class EntranceRate extends Rate { 
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "\"RATES_GRID_ID\"")
 protected RatesGrid ratesGrid;
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name="ecc.\"RATES_GRID\"")
public class RatesGrid extends GenericBusinessObject {
 /** */
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ratesGrid",  targetEntity = EntranceRate.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private List<EntranceRate> entranceRates;
}
```

When I try to access my `entranceRates` list from a `ratesGrid` object, I get this error :

```
Object with id: 151 was not of the specified subclass: com.ecc.bo.rate.EntranceRate (loaded object was of wrong class class com.ecc.bo.rate.AnnualRate)
```

Looking at the sql generated, I found no trace of "discriminator=" in the where clause.
What am I doing wrong ?

I use a PostGreSQL database and a Hibernate as JPA provider.

Comment: If I try to retrieve all entranceRates from database with a jpql query, the sql generated contains the "where discriminator=" clause.
So the problem comes from the mapping in the RatesGrid object but I can't find where.
Thanks,

Julien

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature (for me, it's a bug), but the solution (workaround?) is to use the Hibernate annotation [`@ForceDiscriminator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/ForceDiscriminator.html) on your top class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ecc.\"RATE\"")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForceDiscriminator
public abstract class Rate extends GenericBusinessObject {
    ...
}
```

You might want to vote for [HHH-4358](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-4358).

Comment: As of Hibernate v??, `@ForceDiscriminator` is deprecated , use `@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` instead