# Hibernate - WrongClassException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-onetomany

This is part of the domain model of the music system I'm building:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="library_entities", schema="myschema")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class LibraryEntity {

    public LibraryEntity() {}
    
    // ... some fields and their getters/setters ...

}

@Entity
public abstract class Artist extends LibraryEntity {
    
    public Artist() {}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="artist")
    private Set<Album> albums = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="artist")
    private Set<Track> tracks = new HashSet<>();

    // ... some Artist-specific fields and their getters/setters

    public Set<Album> getAlbums() {
        return this.albums;
    }

    public Set<Track> getTracks() {
        return this.tracks;
    }

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class Band extends Artist {

    public Band() {}

    // ...        
    private Set<Singer> members = new HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class Singer extends Artist {

    public Singer() {}

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="members")
    private Set<Band> bands;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class Album extends LibraryEntity {

    public Album() {}

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="artist_id")
    private Artist artist;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="album")
    private Set<Track> tracks = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Track> getTracks() {
        return this.tracks;
    }

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("T")
public class Track extends LibraryEntity {

    public Track() {}

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="artist_id")
    private Artist artist;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="album_id")
    private Album album;

    public Artist getArtist() {
        return this.artist;
    }

    public Album getAlbum() {
        return this.album;
    }

}
```

Generated schema (as expected):

```
--------------------------------------------
| entity_type | ... | album_id | artist_id |
--------------------------------------------
```

Everything works fine but when I run the following piece of code:

```
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final List<Artist> results =
            entityManager
            .createQuery("SELECT artist FROM Artist artist")
            .getResultList();

        try {

            for(Artist artist : results) {
                artist.getTracks(); // works fine
                artist.getAlbums(); // throws WrongClassException
            }
            
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrack();
        }            

    }

}
```

From tracing the generated SQL query by Hibernate, it's clear that Hibernate is mistakenly fetching a `Track` as an `Album` thus throwing a `WrongClassException`.

```
org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object [id=93c348c2-fb21-4239-9e47-63ef08ae3040] 
was not of the specified subclass [com.database.Models.Album] : loaded object was of 
wrong class class com.database.Models.Track
```

**What am I doing wrong here? Please help.**

**[UPDATE]**
I realized that by calling `artist.getAlbums()` first, the second call (`artist.getTracks()`) fails. And by calling `artist.getTracks()` first, the second call (`artist.getAlbums()`) fails.

**[UPDATE 2]**
The problem vanishes when I remove:

```
public class Album extends LibraryEntity {

    @ManyToOne                      // removed
    @JoinColumn(name="artist_id")   // removed
    private Artist artist;          // removed

}
public class Artist extends LibraryEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="artist")   // removed
    private Set<AlbumModel> albums = new HashSet<AlbumModel>(); //removed

}
```

But, the relationship is absolutely needed since a `Track` can be a single track (thus needing the reference to `Artist`). And an `Album` definitely needs the relationship too.

Comment: Are Track and Album also mapped to a single table with discriminators? I suspect the error is in those entities.

Comment: Could you please help me figure this out? @vlad-mihalcea

Comment: Can you share the result set of 'select * from library_entities'

Comment: Kindly post your `album` and `track` entity

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: LibrarytEntity is not mapped [SELECT entity FROM LibrarytEntity entity]` @null

Comment: They're there @TheCoder

Comment: Sorry, I meant to execute the query from your DB console and share the result.

Comment: Ooh I should've noticed. If you want the generated schema it is already there. I suspect the `artist_id` being used by two entities (both `Album` and `Track`) is causing the problem. But I should examine. @null

Comment: @null Notice [UPDATE 2] please.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the solution.
According to [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8924?focusedCommentId=58128), two classes (in this case `Album` and `Track`) should not be using the same join column (Although I think there should be such a capability).
So by creating a `album_artist_id` and `track_artist_id` the problem is solved.

**Edit:**
I have found a better solution.
I've added another abstract class named `Artwork` which contains the reference to class `Artist`.
Both `Album` and `Track` are derived from `Artwork`.
Also `Artwork` is marked with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.
And `Album` and `Track` have been changed to:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
@AssociationOverride(name="artist", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="album_artist_id"))
public class Album extends Artwork {
    ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("T")
@AssociationOverride(name="artist", 
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="track_artist_id"))
public class Track extends Artwork {
    ...
}
```

At the end we still do have two foreign keys but from the OOP perspective, it is fixed.
Let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This should work when you use `@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)` on `Album` and `Track` to force the type discriminator constraint to be added for the association joins.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: In that case you should create a bug report in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Yes I should. I have also found a workaround for this. @christian-beikov

Comment: check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626030/5612892